# How to reinstall language pack in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, language-pack

I think I've messed up with my Hackintosh's MacOS X install...

I was looking for a way to free up disk space, and I've found the great Monolingual software to remove language packs from my Mac. Happens that I've deleted the French language, thinking in use the Canadian French only (wich is the one I need most). Now I cannot use any french language (even using the languagesetup command, that only gives me the "english" option)

Is there a way to reinstall just the language pack, without reinstalling the whole system? Since it is a Hackintosh with triple boot, reinstalling it means reinstall three OS :(

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/), which should be able to extract a particular font installer package out of the OS X installer.

> **Pacifist** is a shareware application that opens Mac OS X .pkg package files, .dmg disk images, and .zip, .tar, .tar.gz, .tar.bz2, and .xar archives and allows you to extract individual files and folders out of them. This is useful, for instance, if an application which is installed by the operating system becomes damaged and needs to be reinstalled without the hassle of reinstalling all of Mac OS X